# Passing of large array between several C modules

Tags: c, arrays

I have several quite large arrays define in `table.c` (each of them around 1500 members). I need to pass them to different modules and/or provide a method how to update them.

My question is how to make it the most efficient and not to waste memory. My idea is to do the standard `getters/setters`. So if for the `get` I will have a public function:

```
void getTable(tableID, *table)
```

`tableID` will be enum definying witch table I want and the `*table` will be pointer to a table. I guess that just a reference is passed, so the table is not "duplicated" in memory.

And then in the otherModule.c I will jsut call

```
table *myPointer;
getTable(TableA, myPointerTable).
```

Is it correct?

Comment: Accessor functions are an option, but they're not needed. You can simply reference the global objects directly. (E.g., `int x[10] = {...};` in one unit and `extern int x[10];` in a different unit that references `x`) Since arrays decay to pointers in function call, you don't have to worry about any accidental copies, as only pointers will get copied in function calls.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how have you defined those array and how are you planning to use them?

Comment: @PSkocik That leads to spaghetti programming and tight coupling. Very bad idea.

Comment: If is it for me: Save the C arrays in a file, as (binary data) each function want these arrays open-copy from the file to C array

Answer (score 2):

> I have several quite large arrays define in table.c (each of them around 1500 members).

On current laptops (having gigabytes of RAM) an array of a dozen thousands numbers is not a large one, it is a tiny array. Today a large array have at least millions of (machine) numbers, and you'll better use [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) for it.

<sup>(of course, if each element of the array is some complex and heavy data structure - such as some [bignum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) - things are different)</sup>

You could just pass a pointer (to the array, or to some `struct` ending with a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)).

BTW, when passed as arguments, arrays are decayed into pointers (usually, the [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) makes that address *quickly* passed in some [processor register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register)). So something like

```
extern double bigarray[123456];
foo(bigarray);
```

don't *copy* the array (but passes only its address).

> My idea is to do the standard getters/setters.

That could be good, and is probably more readable.

BTW you might define these getters & setters functions as some `static inline` functions in a common header file (to be `#include`-ed appropriately). That would make your code readable and fast.

Comment: Who said that the OP was doing PC programming though?

Comment: I suppose that if it was not the case OP would have *explicitly* told us (about embedded programming, or about HPC on supercomputers)

Answer (score 2):

Array expressions "decay" to pointers in most circumstances, so if you define something like

```
T humongous[50000]; // for some arbitrary type T
```

and pass it to a function like

```
foo( humongous );
```

what `foo` receives is just a pointer to the first element, not the whole array:

```
void foo( T *arr ) { ... }
```

Note that, in the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[N]` and `T a[]` are treated the same as `T *a` - they all declare `a` as a *pointer* to `T`.  Basically, you cannot pass an array "by value" to a function in C.

Now, if your array is a member of a `struct` or `union` type, and you pass an expression of that type to a function, then you *will* be creating a copy of that entire array within the function:

```
struct blah {
  ...
  T humongous[50000];
  ...
} bletch;

foo( bletch );

void foo( struct blah b ) { ... } // b is a full copy of bletch
```

so in that case you'll probably want to a pass a *pointer* to `bletch` instead:

```
foo( &bletch );

void foo( struct blah *b ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Setters/getters might be an ok idea for smaller programs, although you probably want the format as

```
table_t* getTable (tableID)
```

However, this isn't a pure getter function in an OO sense, since you expose private data through a pointer. In addition, re-entrancy might become an issue with this method. For larger professional programs, that need to be maintained over a longer period of time, this won't do.

The best solution is to leave the allocation to the caller. You can do this indirectly by using *opaque pointers*:

table.h

```
typedef struct table_t table_t; // forward declaration

table_t* table_init (size_t size, /* stuff */);

void table_free (table_t* table);
```

table.c:

```
#include "table.h"

struct table_t // this will be unknown to the caller
{ 
  // private, encapsulated data:
  size_t size;
  int data[]; // flexible array member
};

table_t* table_init (size_t size, /* stuff */)
{
  table_t* result = malloc(sizeof(*result) + int[size]);
  if(result == NULL) { /* handle errors */ }

  result->size = size;
  do_something(result->data);

  return result;
}

void table_free (table_t* table)
{
  free(table);
  /* optionally, make the parameter table_t** and set the pointer 
     to NULL after calling free() */
}
```

caller.c:

```
#include "table.h"

table_t* table = table_init(n, /* stuff */);

table_do_stuff(table); // either setter/getter or actual algorithm

table_free(table);
```

This gives a proper design and allows multiple instances, which also sorts out the re-entrancy issue.

Comment: Minor: `table.h` needs an include for `size_t`.  Perhaps `<stddef.h>`?

Comment: @chux Yeah, this is kind of pseudo-code. Header also needs header guards and so on.